# How to inherit a class and pass over a PanacheRepository

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm creating an application in Kotlin and Quarkus. I'm now creating a generic rest resource, which will be extended by my other resource classes. The idea would be that I will have to write less code, as all methods of the generic class will be used by its children. Now the problem I'm having is to pass a generic PanacheRepository.

All methods in the GenericResource use PanacheRepository methods. But when I try to pass for example a UserRepository over to the GenericResource through the constructor, it doesn't work.

Below is my GenericResource:

```
class GenericResource(
    val repository: PanacheRepository<Any>
    ) {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun findAll() : FindAllResponse =
        try {
            FindAllSuccess(repository.listAll())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            FindAllFailure(e)
        }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    fun add(
        @Valid user: User
    ) : AddResponse =
        try {
            repository.persist(user)
            AddSuccess(user)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AddFailure(e)
        }

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    fun findById(
        @PathParam("userId")
        userId : UUID
    ) : FindResponse =
        try {
            FindSuccess(
                repository.find("id", userId).firstResult()
            )
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
            FindFailure(e)
        }

    @PATCH
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{userId}")
    fun update(
        @PathParam("userId")
        userId : UUID,
        user: User
    ) : UpdateResponse =
        try {
            user.id?.let { user.fullName?.let { it1 ->
                user.email?.let { it2 ->
                    repository.update("fullName = ?1, email = ?2 where id = ?3",
                        it1, it2, it)
                }
            } }
            UpdateSuccess(user)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            UpdateFailure(e)
        }

    @DELETE
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{userId}")
    fun delete(
        @PathParam("userId")
        userId : UUID
    ) : DeleteResponse =
        try {
            repository.delete("id", userId)
            DeleteSuccess("User deleted.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            DeleteFailure(e)
        }

}
```

And this would be my UserResource:

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
class UserRes(user: User) : GenericResource(user) {
}
```

I also have a separate UserRepository which is this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class UserRepository : PanacheRepository<User>
```

Can someone push me into the right direction? Quite new to Kotlin still :)

Comment: What means not working?, do you have a stacktrace or something ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. By using generics I'm able to pass my entities to the GenericResource:

```
open class GenericResource<T : Any>(
    @ApplicationScoped
    private var repository: PanacheRepository<T>
    ) {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun findAll() : FindAllResponse =
        try {
            FindAllSuccess(repository.listAll())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            FindAllFailure(e)
        }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    fun add(
        @Valid resource: T
    ) : AddResponse =
        try {
            repository.persist(resource)
            AddSuccess(resource)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            AddFailure(e)
        }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun findById(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID
    ) : FindResponse =
        try {
            FindSuccess(
                repository.find("id", id).firstResult()
            )
        } catch (e: NotFoundException) {
            FindFailure(e)
        }

    @PUT
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun update(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID,
        resource: T
    ) : UpdateResponse =
        try {
            repository.persist(resource)
            UpdateSuccess(resource)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            UpdateFailure(e)
        }

    @DELETE
    @Transactional
    @Path("/{id}")
    fun delete(
        @PathParam("id")
        id : UUID
    ) : DeleteResponse =
        try {
            repository.delete("id", id)
            DeleteSuccess("User deleted.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            DeleteFailure(e)
        }

}
```

And the UserResource which will be using it:

```
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
class UserResource(user: UserRepository) : GenericResource<User>(user)
```